# Converting TIFF to PDF with GraphicsMagick MediaBox / CropBox resolution

Tags: imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

We are currently converting TIFF files to PDF using GraphicsMagick. The TIFF is coming from an eFAX and has a (pixel) resolution of 1728x2200.

If you do the conversion with tiff2pdf or just open it on Preview and convert export it to PDF, it is generated with a MediaBox value of 612x792 point, which is what is expected.

However graphics magick generates a MediaBox of 1728x4400 and a CropBox of 610x792. It all looks good if you open it on a PDF viewer because it's using the CropBox but if you're feeding it to GhostScript after, you don't get the Image on the full page but as a small square inside the document.

The lazy solutions would be to change for Tiff2PDF or add -dUseCropBox to our GhostScript command but I'd like to know what GraphicsMagick option should be used to have the PDF with the good MediaBox. It's like it doesn't understand that the resolution is in Pixels and not in Point. Hope somebody has insights

Comment: I suspect **GraphicsMagick** works the same as **ImageMagick**. It probably assumes a default 72 dpi. The solution is normally to set the dpi explicitly. So, either `gm convert -density 144x144 input.xyz ... output.abc` or `gm convert input.xyz -set density 288x288 ... output.abc`. HTH.

Comment: density only plays with the CropBox and not the media box, sadly. Resample works but it gives a lower quality :(